# Loading / opening process for a QGIS-project does not fully complete (hang-up)

Tags: qgis, windows-10

The loading / opening process for one specific QGIS-project does not fully complete. The process seems to work fine until the message in the bottom bar states "Loading layer myshapefile.shp" and the loading process bar shows 100%. Then it looks like it runs into a hang-up: no error message appears and the blue circle on the screen remains spinning.

Some remarks:

- The only property which clearly distinguishes the affected QGIS-project from other QGIS-projects is the large number of 20 layouts.
- The affected QGIS-project has been,  without difficulty, closed and re-opened several times before without any modification.
- The sources behind the individual layers are neither missing nor corrupted as tests with other QGIS-projects and other GIS applications verify.
- This problem occurs for multiple users' accounts and on different hardware.
- The last layer mentioned in the message is a shapefile. However, it's not clear whether the problem is due to this layer or whether this layer is just the last layer in the loading process without causing the problem.

If the reason for this hang-up can not get resolved, is there any option to disassemble layers or layouts - best bit by bit - prior to the opening process in order to unburden the opening process?

Technical parameters:

- QGIS version: 3.28.1-Firenze
- Operating System: Windows 11 Pro, 21H2

Comment: did you findany solution to that?

Comment: I moved the last loaded layer to a different place on the harddisk to provoke a broken datasource. Than I was able to open and save the project.

Comment: Sometimes it is a rendering issue, especially if you have large datasets. Try the following steps (1) open qgis, (2) disable rendering (see check box located at bottom right in QGIS), and (3) then load the project.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue. For me, the layer that was showing as still/last loading was a layer I had tinkered with to reduce its size and speed up loading and handling. It was a GPKG vector subset of a larger file from which I had deleted 90% of all attributes. But in memory it was still showing as the same size of the very much larger original dataset.....(something to do with the database registry still holding the deleted fields, just not rendering them).

Waited 12 hrs for the project to load (it eventually does!), resaved the GPKG, checked it had reduced in size, saved the project. The same delay occurred when I tried to close the project file for a reboot.

Hard reboot, and the project opened in under a minute.

Similar issue seems to arise when clipping Rasters. The fractional clip seems to be the same size as its original parent ......? Compressing the file either on clipping or after clipping reduces the file size as would be expected.

I have no understanding of what is going on, but resolved the issue as above.